# Why does my .java file disable errorchecking?

Tags: java, processing, code-completion, error-checking

Recently I've added a `.java` file to my Processing Project (its called `GClip.java` from a library which is called G4P). That `.java` file helps to copy stuff to the clipboard. I read that on a forum, however directly after I created a new Tab and imported the content from the `.java` file it gave me that message:

> sketch_190108b contains .java tabs.  Some editor features (like
>   completion and error checking) will be disabled.

Now I can't see errors and stuff. How can I turn it back on? I've already tried turning it on in the preferences tab but it didn't work... Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is this is because the error checking comes from the Processing preprocessor, which turns Processing code into Java code. If you're using a `.java` file, then the prepocessor is skipped, so it can't do its error checking.

If you want to be sure, you could search for the message in the Processing source code [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/tree/master/core/src/processing/core).

You might consider using a Java IDE like Eclipse or Intellij if this is important to you.

Also, please make sure you're following the G4P copyright license when you copy its code.